# Adding a external hyperlink to an Angular Material data table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm on Angular CLI 13.1.2 and I'm trying to pass data to the table that is a hyperlink outside of the application. I've been unable to get the get the link to open successfully (in a new tab). When hovering over the link, it thinks it is part of the application - `www.localhost:4200/www.google.com`.

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="p2_offering">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><!-- P2 Offering --></th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  <a href="www.google.com"> Some link </a>  </td>
      </ng-container>
```

How can I fix this to open the new page on click instead of being interpreted as part of the application?

Comment: Have you tried to prepend your link with `https://`?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing...